# Axios GET is sending the same url multiple times in Promise chain

Tags: node.js, es6-promise, axios

I have a Promise chain that runs like this:

```
// this part is not meant to be syntactically correct
axios.get(<rest_api_that_queries_a_list_of_car_models>).then(res => {
  // loop thru list and call a custom module promise
  for (...) {
    mymodule.getSomething(args).then(res => {
      axios.post(<rest_write_to_db>).then(res => {
        //we're done
....

// in mymodule
function getSomething(args) {
  return getAnotherThing(args).then(res => {
    // do stuff
    return aThing
...
function getAnotherThing(args) {
  return getThatThing(args).then(res => {
    // see if pagination is greater than 1 page
    if (pages == 1)
      return res

    let promises = [res]
    for (x=2;x<pages;x++) {
      // change args
      promises.push( getThatThing(args))
    }
    return Promise.all(promises)
  }).then(allres => {
    return allres
  })
  ...
// this is where it's breaking.  this part is syntactically accurate
function getThatThing(args) {
  let params = Object.assign(BASE_PARAMS, args.params)
  console.log(args.params.model) // this logs prints a different model everytime
  return axios.get(URL, {
     headers: {
        "Accept": ACCEPT,
        "Content-Type":CONTENT_TYPE,
     },
     params: params
   }).then (response => { 
     console.log(response.request.path) // this path includes the last key only everytime. so if there are 10 car models, this will search for the last model 10 times.
     let result = response.data
     return result
   }).catch(function (error) {
     console.log("search error:",error);
     return error.response.data.errorMessage[0].error[0].message[0]
   })
 }
```

So basically the issue is that the axios.get command in the last function is using the same get parameters even tho I'm printing different parameters right before I make the call.  I don't see how that is possible.

Comment: mymodule.getSomething() pass args from that call, you are calling it without args

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by changing this line

```
let params = Object.assign(BASE_PARAMS, args.params)
```

to this

```
let params = {...BASE_PARAMS, ...args.params}
```

I can't really tell you why this fixed it.  I'm assuming the Object.assign set the value to params on a global level.  Perhaps someone else could provide more insight.